# Command line tool to extract lines from a text file

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a large file (say `reads.fasta`) which has around 5,000,000 lines and have another file `reads_of_interest` which contains a list of the line numbers of `reads.fasta` that I want to extract.

Is there an easy command line method to do this?

In other words, there is a file `large_file.txt`. There is another file `line_numbers.txt` which is of the form

```
12 
134
1456
```

And I want to extract lines `12`, `134`, `1456` from `large_file.txt`. The number of lines I want to extract is of the order of 500,000.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you update question to include typical line length ?  Could be that the file could comfortably sit in memory in a perl/awk array.

Comment: 5mil *lines* is ridiculous. are you *sure* that is the best way to delimit the file? has it been *blocked* such that the lines are fixed width? that would be the sane way to go so you could just seek through to offsets. in any case, you'll find benchmarks for several different solutions against a 5mil lines file at this duplicate question: [Filter File by Line Number](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209441/52934)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that was exactly what I was looking for. The file is a very file of DNA reads. I wanted to restrict the downstream processing to a particular  subset of reads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an easy and direct way to get what you want.  The problem here is that the entire `large_file.txt` will be scanned.  If this is too slow there are other things to try.  One of which would be loading the file into a database keyed on the line numbers, which would give extremely fast retrieval compared to scanning the file.

```
#!/bin/sh
awk '
    NR == FNR {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            linenums[$i]
        }
    }
    NR != FNR {
        if (FNR in linenums) {
            print
        }
    }
' line_numbers.txt large_file.txt
```

`NR` is the current record number (Number of Records), and `FNR` is the current record number within the current file.

So when `NR == NFR` awk is processing the first file arg, when `NR != NFR` `awk` is processing the second (or later) file.

This reads all of the line numbers from `line_numbers.txt` and stores them as keys into an array with no data elements, only keys (the `linenums` array).

When the second file, `large_file.txt`, is being read, if the current record number has been stored as a key in the array `linenums`, then the line from `large_file.txt` will be printed.

The method of looking up the line numbers in the `linenums` array is relatively fast because `awk` uses an internal hashing algorithm to lookup the keys.

Comment: *If this is too slow there are other things to try. One of which would be loading the file into a database keyed on the line numbers, which would give extremely fast retrieval compared to scanning the file.*  That would be *much* faster, but readers need to note that the original loading of the file into the DB would be slower than just extracting the desired lines as both require reading the entire file, but only one requires inserting the data into the DB.  If you need to extract lines more than one time, that (or similar pre-splitting) is by far the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming file_numbers.txt contains a single line and if that line is not too large, the following should work

```
sed -n "$(<file_numbers.txt sed -e "s/ /p;/g" -e "s/$/p/")" large_file.txt
```

Comment: I suggest changing that to `sed -n -f <(<file_numbers.txt sed -e 's/ /p;/g' -e 's/$/p/') large_file.txt`, so you don't pass the entire command list on the command line.  Actually, I would say `sed -n -f <(sed -e 's/ /p;/g' -e 's/$/p/' file_numbers.txt) large_file.txt`, because I don't like putting I/O redirection first.  Also, you should document your assumptions.

Comment: thats not gonna work for 500k lines.

Comment: @mikeserv, not sure what you mean - `file_numbers.txt` is a single-line file. It's `large_file.txt` that's 500k lines long

Comment: largefile is 5mil lines and linenumbers is 500k.